# What's the most concise way in javascript to find consecutive dups in an array, sum them up and reiterate?

Tags: javascript, arrays

#### Example

I have an array of:

```
const myArr = [1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3];
```

If I were pass it to the function it should produce the output like so:

```
//result: [2, 1, 3, 8, 3]
```

The consecutive first two `1`s and `2`s were consecutive duplicates so they were summed up.

The first two consecutive `1`s became `2` so it now doesn't match.

The consecutive `2`s became `4` so it matched the next running number and summed up again resulting in an `8`

Although the `3`s are duplicate they we're not summed up because they're not consecutive

---

#### Bonus

- It would be great if someone can demonstrate this using javascript's array functions `map` or `reduce`.
- <strike>Is this possible without any kind of recursion?</strike> someone mentioned its possible, then I'd be nice if it didn't use recursion

---

#### EDIT

Adding this here because some have already provided answers.

In the case of:

```
const myArr = [1, 1, 1, 1];
// result: [4]

const myArr = [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3];
// result: [4, 3, 8, 3]
```

Another interesting case that didn't pass my mind:

```
const myArr = [1, 1, 2, 2];
//result [4, 2] instead of [2,4]
```

It should check against the new array as soon a change was made

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Everything that is possible with recursion is possible without. You should specify the problem more clearly (for instance, what happens on 3, 3, 3?) and write up what you've attempted and ask specific questions about problems you ran into.

Comment: If I have [2, 2, 2] should the function return [4, 2] or [6]?

Comment: The "*result `[4, 2]` instead of `[2,4]`*" test case doesn't seem to follow the algorithm given in your title. "*find consecutive dups in an array, sum them up and reiterate*" would take all the sums into account only in the next iteration, not each on its own before finding the next duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the assumption that this will be used only on arrays of numbers, this is simple enough to do with reduce.

```
function duplicateAddition(input) {
    var last;
    var result = input;
    do {
        last = result;
        result = last.reduce(function (carry, item) {
            if (carry[carry.length - 1] == item) {
                carry[carry.length - 1] *= 2;
            } else {
                carry.push(item);
            }
            return carry;
        }, []);
    } while (last.length != result.length);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This does not work for `[1, 1, 1, 1]` - the expected result is `[4]` not `[2, 2]`. You need to do multiple passes until nothing changes, or do sophisticated backtracking.

Comment: Wow, could you share how did u come up with this?

Comment: @jkris, the method is fairly simple if you just take it a step at a time. I'm really just checking to see if the previous element of the array is equal to the current element. If it is, then I double the last element. If not, then the current element should be added to the results array as it is different.

Comment: It does however also fail the test for `[1, 1, 2, 2]` that should yield `[2, 4]` - doing only one pass

Comment: Oh wait, I've mixed them up. `[4, 2]` is expected. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Oh good, I thought I was going crazy as I couldn't tell where that came from.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the array always contains numbers, the most concise I can think of would be

```
function merge(arr) {
    var x = String(arr),
        y = x.replace(/([^,]),\1/, (_,m)=>2*m);
    return x.length == y.length ? y.split(",").map(Number) : merge(y);
}
```

If you want to avoid the tail recursion, it's trivial to convert that to a loop:

```
function merge(arr) {
    var y = String(arr);
    do {
        var x = y;
        y = x.replace(/([^,]),\1/, (_,m)=>2*m);
    } while(x.length != y.length)
    return y.split(",").map(Number);
}
```

or

```
function merge(arr) {
    for (var x=String(arr), y=""; x.length!=y.length; x=y.replace(/([^,]),\1/, (_,m)=>2*m))
        y=x;
    return x.split(",").map(Number);
}
```

Btw, to alter the behaviour of the algorithm to get `[2, 4]` instead of `[4, 2]` from `[1, 1, 2, 2]` (i.e. find *all* duplicates and sum them before reiterating), you'd only need to add the `/g`lobal flag to the regex.

Comment: This is definitely more concise than my answer, but understanding it is rather painful. +1

Comment: @Gerrit0 the loops are painful, I agree, but the recursive version should be trivial if you recognise the regex pattern for detecting duplicates

Comment: @jkris Possibly because numbers are numbers and should be operated on as numbers, not strings.

Comment: @torazaburo Unfortunately I have not yet found a regular expression library that operates on lists of symbols from an arbitrary alphabet instead of being limited to character-sequences :-) Joke aside, I understand the downsides, this answer was written in a mindset that would fit better at [codegolf.SE] (triggered by the term "concise")

Comment: @Bergi I'm tempted to downvote this because you failed to use `eval`.

Comment: @torazaburo you mean `eval('['+x+']')`? Thanks for the tip :-)

Comment: Right, replace the comma with a plus sign and bingo.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses a recursive generator. It has the advantage that it pretty much says what it means and does what it says.

```js
function* x([first, second, ...rest]) {
  if (first !== undefined) {
    if (first !== second) yield first; else second *= 2;
    yield* x([second, ...x(rest)]);
  }
}

function test(a) { console.log(Array.from(x(a))); }

test([1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3]);
test([1, 1, 1, 1]);
test([1, 1, 2, 2]);
```

In this solution, the input `[1, 1, 2, 2]` produces `[2, 4]`. That is because the logic greedily collapses the `2, 2` into a `4`, which then does not match the `2` resulting from `1, 1`. If this behavior is not desired, then it might suffice to change the line above to:

```
yield* x([second, ...rest]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple game of unshifting from array `a` to pushing array `b`. So if `a[0] === a[1]` you take the first two items from array `a`, get their sum and push it into array `b` but if `a[0] !== a[1]` then take only the first item and push it into array `b`. However before we push the interim value (`t` in below snippet) we check the last item of array `b` to see if it's equal to the interim. If they are equal we just double the last item of array `b` if not just push interim (`t`) over `b`.

Then make a tail call optimized recursive invoking.

```js
function sumAndReduce(a, b = []){
  var t = 0;
  if (!a.length) return b;
  t = a[0] === a[1] ? a.splice(0,2).reduce((p,c) => p+c)
                    : a.splice(0,1)[0];
  b[b.length-1] === t ? b[b.length-1] += t
                      : b.push(t);
  return sumAndReduce(a,b);
}

var myArr = [1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3],
   result = sumAndReduce(myArr);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
console.log(JSON.stringify(sumAndReduce([1, 1, 1, 1])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(sumAndReduce([1, 1, 2, 2])));
```

Well... if you don't want recursion even if it is a tail call optimized one, then it's very trivial to convert the above code into an iterative one with a while loop. I'll leave it to you..!

So i can not make sure if your request as per an input `[1,1,2,2]` breaks the initial conditions but here is a modified version of the above code to comply with that as well.

```js
function sumAndReduce(a, b = []){
  var t = 0;
  if (!a.length) return b;
  t = a[0] !== a[1] || b[b.length-1] === a[0] ? a.splice(0,1)[0]
                                              : a.splice(0,2).reduce((p,c) => p+c);
  b[b.length-1] === t ? b[b.length-1] += t
                      : b.push(t);
  return sumAndReduce(a,b);
}

var myArr = [1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3],
   result = sumAndReduce(myArr);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
console.log(JSON.stringify(sumAndReduce([1, 1, 1, 1])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(sumAndReduce([1, 1, 2, 2])));
```

Comment: You should not initialise `t` to an array when it will become a number.

Comment: @Bergi yes true it's my overlooking, a left over from a previous version. Yet i have to fix the code as per the third condition, the `[4,2]` thingy as well.